# Null check operator used on a null value al usar initialpage de pageview

Tags: android, flutter, dart

me salta el error Null check operator used on a null value al utilizar la variable int? pageIdx e inicializar el initpage: pageIdx!, se que es por que puse pageIdx!, pero no encuentro otra forma de hacer que el pageview comience donde lo deje una vez que cambio de pantalla con el bottomnavigationBar, ya que si inicializo en int pageIdx = 0 o uso pageIdx??0 en initialpage siempre me regresa al indice 0. Estoy usando shared preferences para guardar la posicion del pageview, y todo bien, pero al iniciar el pageview si me inicia en la posicion donde lo deje pero antes me sale por unos breves milisegundos el mensaje de error. Adjunto el código.

videoscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/constants.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/controllers/cache_controller.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/controllers/download_data.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/controllers/video_controller.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/views/widgets/circle_animation.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/views/widgets/video_player_iten.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
//import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  //final int page;

  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

final VideoController videoController = Get.put(VideoController());
Cache clearCache = Cache();
final DownloadFile downFile = DownloadFile();

buildMusicAlbum(String profilePhoto) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(11),
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.grey,
                    Colors.white,
                  ],
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(profilePhoto),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ))
      ],
    ),
  );
}

buildProfile(String profilePhoto) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    child: Stack(children: [
      Positioned(
        left: 5,
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(profilePhoto),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]),
  );
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
 int? _pageIdx;
 
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    readData();
  }

//save pageview index via sharepreferences
  saveIndex(final dataTosave) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (dataTosave == null) {
      prefs.setInt('index_page', 0);
    } else {
      prefs.setInt('index_page', dataTosave);
    }
  }

//load pageview index via sharepreferences
  void readData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getInt('index_page') == null) {
      setState(() => _pageIdx = 0);
    } else {
      setState(() => _pageIdx = prefs.getInt('index_page')!);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        children: [
          Obx(() {
            return PageView.builder(
              itemCount: videoController.videoList.length,
              onPageChanged: (idx) {
                saveIndex(idx);
              },
              controller: PageController(initialPage: _pageIdx!),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final data = videoController.videoList[index];
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    VideoPlayerItem(
                      videoUrl: data.videoUrl,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 20,
                                  ),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        data.username,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        data.description,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          const Icon(
                                            Icons.person,
                                            size: 15,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            data.speaker,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 470,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height / 4),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    buildProfile(
                                      data.profilePhoto,
                                    ),
                                    // _navBarSuperior(),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () => videoController
                                              .likeVideo(data.id),
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.favorite,
                                            size: 30,
                                            color: data.likes.contains(
                                                    authController.user.uid)
                                                ? Colors.red
                                                : Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                        Text(
                                          data.likes.length.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            downFile.videofunction(
                                                data.videoUrl,
                                                data.nameVideo); //aqui se llama a la funcion de descarga
                                            const snackbar = SnackBar(
                                              content: Text('Descargando!!!!'),
                                            );
                                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                .showSnackBar(snackbar);
                                          },
                                          child: const Icon(
                                            Icons.download,
                                            size: 30,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                        Text(
                                          'Descargar'.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            Share.share(
                                                "Esto es un texto compartido desde Video Application");
                                          },
                                          child: const Icon(
                                            Icons.reply,
                                            size: 30,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                        Text(
                                          'Compartir'.toString(),
                                          // data.shareCount.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            clearCache.clearCache();
                                            const snackbar = SnackBar(
                                              content: Text('Actualizando!!!!'),
                                            );
                                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                .showSnackBar(snackbar);
                                          },
                                          child: const Icon(
                                            Icons.refresh,
                                            size: 30,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                        Text(
                                          'Actualizar'.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    CircleAnimation(
                                      child: buildMusicAlbum(data.profilePhoto),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

y este es el codigo de mi bottomnavigationBar.

Home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tiktok_tutorial/constants.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int pageIdx = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: 56,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: (idx) {
            setState(() {
              pageIdx = idx;
            });
          },
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 95, 199),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          currentIndex: pageIdx,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 18),
              label: 'Inicio',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 18),
              label: 'Busqueda',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded, size: 23),
              //icon: CustomIcon(),
              label: 'Descubrir',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book, size: 18),
              label: 'Catalogo',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person, size: 18),
              label: 'Perfil',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: pages[pageIdx],
    );
  }
}
```

Adjunto gif.
[image: error]

Comment: Utiliza un indexedsatck como widget en el parámetro body del scaffold, así podrás mantener el estado de tus widgets, aunque los cambies.

Comment: En videoscreen.dart o en mi home donde tengo el botónnavigationBar??? Perdón, no tiene mucho que empecé en flutter y aún ando aprendiendo...

Comment: En el home. indexedStack es un stack que muestra solo un elemento, pero los demás siguen en memoria, de esa forma, aunque cambies de pantalla, la anterior no muere y cuando vuelvas a ella seguirá exactamente igual que como la dejaste, por lo que no necesitarás saber en qué vídeo te quedaste, por tanto, tampoco necesitarás guardar el último vídeo que viste

Comment: Gracias bro, estuve investigando el tema y lo implementé y funciona de maravilla, muchas gracias Hermano :)

Comment: este video te ayudará @GustavoJose https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v4ZofYsn5I